# Can't change content and sidebar width

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to change content and sidebar width of my site http://www.howto-connect.com/. Unfortunately, I can't get a positive result. You can laugh at this simple question. But after making changes in CSS is not giving output. Thanks in advance for a help.

Comment: you really need to post the code you are working with.

Comment: I am trying to change through #sidebar-container {
    width: 38%;
    position: relative;
}

Comment: I want more space between sidebar and content and decrease the sidebar width

Comment: hello, Stuart, kindly help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to delete cache?
If you have a cache plugin on your site, try to delete cache and you can reload your browser without cache as well.

I had a look and it is #sidebar-container { width: 38%; position: relative; }

Comment: thanks Andrew, I find no alteration even after clearing browser, site cache. Also tried in incognito.

Answer (score 0):

Answering "I want more space between sidebar and content and decrease the sidebar width"

Your `#content` is `70%`, and `#sidebar-container` is `30%`. Change these to how wide you need the sidebar, then add this css to your `#content`:

```
padding-right: 40px;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Changing the 40px to how much "more space between sidebar and content" you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can paste this css in your stylesheet

```
#content {
    width: 69%;
}

#sidebar-container {
    margin-left: 22px;
    width: 28%;
}
```

If still does not work for you then use **! important** like that.

```
#sidebar-container {
        margin-left: 22px !important;
        width: 28% !important;
    }
```

It will prioritise your css.